# Help identifying this perennial grass-like plant

Tags: grass, perennials, deer

I live in Ohio and just purchased a home that has this decorative grass-like plant that grows in tufts pictured here.  It didn't seem to bloom last year, but this year it did (then again, I accidentally killed all of it last year with the leaf blower because the elderly woman who owned the home couldn't take care of the leaves the last couple years).

[image]

Other Notes:

- It's deer resistant, as prior owners chose a lot of deer resistant plants and
  the deer seem to mostly ignore it.
- It's a perennial.
- It spreads like wildfire, as this year it has popped up randomly all over the yard.

Can anyone identify this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Galanthus nivalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galanthus_nivalis) and it grows from perennial bulbs, that's why it comes back every year. If you want it to spread, separate the bulbs every few years. If you want to get rid of it, dig out the bulbs and cut the leaves as early as possible for the ones that you miss when digging out.

Comment: I believe that's it!  So in theory, I can dig out the bulbs of the ones that popped up where I don't want them and replant them in the area I do want them?

Comment: Yes, of course. If the flowers wilt after transplant, no problem. Next year they will bloom again.